# contador en un switch php no funciona?

Tags: php, contador, switch

estoy programando un acumulador en php dentro de un switch pero no hace la función ni opera. lo detallo de varias formas y nada.

```
`if (isset($_POST['numero'])) {
        $cadena = 0;
        $num = 0;
        switch ($_POST['numero']) {
            case 'uno':
                $num = 1;
                //$mensaje .= "Monto Agregado" . "<br/>";
                //$cadena .=   $num;
                $cadena .= $num;
                break;
                $cadena = $cadena;
    
            case 'dos':
                $num = 2;
                //$mensaje .= "Monto Agregado" . "<br/>";
                $cadena .= $num;
                break;
                $cadena = $cadena;
                $cadena .= $num;
                $mensaje = print_r($mensaje, true);
                break;
        }
    }`
```

cual es el orden correcto o el switch inclusive invertí el orden dentro de los validadores. ya he subtotalizado en otros módulos y todo bien.

Actualización del formulario completo en donde el proceso esta en un include directamente. proceso que he ocupado en otras aplicaciones.

```
`<?php
    include "plantilla/header.php";
    include "Operaciones.php";
    ?>
    
    <body>
        <header class="header">
            <section class="hero-section">
                <div class="hero-mask">
                </div>
                <!--//hero-mask-->
                <div class="container text-center py-5">
                    <div class="single-col-max mx-auto">
                        <div class="hero-heading-upper pt-3 mb-3">Tecnologia PHP <br class="d-md-none">CERASAM</div>
                        <h1 class="hero-heading mb-5">
                            <span class="brand mb-4 d-block"><span class="text-highlight pr-2">{</span><span class="name">Calculadora</span><span class="text-highlight pl-2">}</span></span>
                            <span class="desc d-block">Calculos Basicos</span>
                        </h1>
                    </div>
                    <!--//single-col-max-->
                </div>
                <!--//container-->
    
            </section>
            <!--//hero-section-->
        </header>
        <!--//header-->

<div class="sections-wrapper">
        <div class="section-blocks mb-5">
            <div id="section-requirements" class="section-requirements section">
                <div class="container py-5">
                    <div class="section-col-max mx-auto">
                        <?php if ($mensaje != "") { ?>
                            <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                                <?php
                                echo $mensaje;
                                ?>
                            </div>
                        <?php } ?>
                        <br>
                        <div class="lead-form-wrapper single-col-max mx-auto theme-bg-light rounded p-5">
                            <div class="form-wrapper">
                                <form class="lead-form" method="POST" action="">
                                    <div class="form-group mb-3">
    
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control " id="resultado" value="<?php echo $cadena ?>" placeholder="resultado de la operacion" readonly>
    
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group mb-3">
                                        <button type="submit" name="operador" value="entre" id="entre" class="btn btn-dark btn-submit w-24">/</button>
                                        <button type="submit" name="operador" value="por" id="por" class="btn btn-dark btn-submit w-24">*</button>
                                        <button type="submit" name="operador" value="menos" id="menos" class="btn btn-dark btn-submit w-24">-</button>
                                        <button type="submit" name="operador" value="mas" id="mas" class="btn btn-dark btn-submit w-24">+</button>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group mb-3">
                                        <button type="submit" name="siete" value="siete" id="siete" class="btn btn-warning btn-submit w-24">7</button>
                                        <button type="submit" name="ocho" value="ocho" id="ocho" class="btn btn-warning btn-submit w-24">8</button>
                                        <button type="submit" name="nueve" value="nueve" id="nueve" class="btn btn-warning btn-submit w-24">9</button>
                                        <button type="submit" name="variable" value="ce" id="ce" class="btn btn-info btn-submit w-24">c</button>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group mb-3">
                                        <button type="submit" name="cuatro" value="cuatro" id="cuatro" class="btn btn-warning btn-submit w-24">4</button>
                                        <button type="submit" name="cinco" value="cinco" id="cinco" class="btn btn-warning btn-submit w-24">5</button>
                                        <button type="submit" name="seis" value="seis" id="seis" class="btn btn-warning btn-submit w-24">6</button>
                                        <button type="submit" name="variable" value="r" id="r" class="btn btn-info btn-submit w-24">R</button>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group mb-3">
                                        <button type="submit" name="numero" value="uno" id="uno" class="btn btn-warning btn-submit w-24">1</button>
                                        <button type="submit" name="numero" value="dos" id="dos" class="btn btn-warning btn-submit w-24">2</button>
                                        <button type="submit" name="tres" value="tres" id="tres" class="btn btn-warning btn-submit w-24">3</button>
                                        <button type="submit" name="variable" value="delete" id="delete" class="btn btn-info btn-submit w-24">
                                            <</button> </div> <div class="form-group mb-4">
                                                <button type="submit" name="numero" value="cero" id="cero" class="btn btn-success btn-submit w-24">0</button>
                                                <button type="submit" name="operador" value="igual" id="igual" class="btn btn-danger btn-submit w-48">=</button>
                                                <button type="submit" name="numero" value="punto" id="punto" class="btn btn-info btn-submit w-24">.</button>
                                    </div>
    
                                </form>
                            </div>
                            <!--//form-wrapper-->
                        </div>
                        <!--//lead-form-wrapper-->
    
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--//container-->
            </div>
            <!--//section-requirements-->
        </div>
        <!--//sections-block-->
    </div>
    <!--//section-wrapper-->`
```

bendito PHP, he leído que string no se pueden concatenar con números pero no se si es mito.

form actualizado completo

Comment: En primer lugar NADA que pongas después de `break` se ejecutará y debes poner un solo `break` al final cada `case`. En segundo lugar, ¿qué es lo que quieres hacer con este código y qué te hace pensar que usar `switch` es la mejor manera para resolverlo? Intuyo que puedes prescindir de  `switch` y simplificar tu código.

Comment: Si no hace la función quiere decir que no está entrando al `switch`, edita la pregunta y muestra el formulario de donde viene el campo `'numero'`. Por cierto, la instrucción `$cadena .= $num` va a generar algo como esto: `'0111...'` ¿Es realmente lo que necesitas?

Comment: @A.Cedano gracias, entiendo lo del break,  he hecho cosas mas avanzadas pero en este caso mi hija esta incursionando en programación básica y estoy apoyandola en el desarrollo de una calculadora mi fuerte es java  php es empirico.  inclusive en php hago contadores sin ningun problema.

Comment: @aeportugal justo es lo que necesito.  el form es el siguiente

Comment: faltaria el inicio del form. puedes añadirlo? asi no sabemos si envia a la pagina correcta (el action del form)

Comment: @Jakala actualizo el formulario completo.

Comment: te planteo una prueba: justo antes del If  escribe un `print_r($_POST)`, y mira que resultado te da. Por lo que veo de tu formulario, solo podria entrar en el if si pulsas los botones de 0, 1, 2 o `.` (ya que el resto no se llaman `numero`).

Comment: @Jakala `Array ( [numero] => uno )` y solo le he aplicado 2 casos por eso solo funciona al activar el boton uno y dos, una vez me funcione al 100% agrego los demas. en teoria deberia clickear ambos botones y como dice @aeportugal deberia generar '012112...'

Answer (score 1):

La estructura de `switch ... case` viene claramente descrita en el [Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/control-structures.switch.php) y es la siguiente:

```
<?php
switch ($i) {
    case 0:
        echo "i es igual a 0";
        break;
    case 1:
        echo "i es igual a 1";
        break;
    case 2:
        echo "i es igual a 2";
        break;
    default:
       echo "i no es igual a 0, 1 ni 2";
}
```

Por tanto, si quieres usar `switch ... case` **debes desarrollar la lógica de cada `case` antes del `break`**, porque éste detiene la evaluación, volviendo al llamador.

Sea como sea, **NO necesitas `switch ... case` para esto**, puedes resolverlo con un simple array donde asocies cada nombre de número a su valor. Luego, buscas cada número por ese índice en el array.

Veamos:

```
$numbers = array( 
                  'cero'=>0,  'uno'=>1,  'dos'=>2,   'tres'=>3, 'cuatro'=>4, 
                  'cinco'=>5, 'seis'=>6, 'siete'=>7, 'ocho'=>8, 'nueve'=>9
                );

$posted=strtolower($_POST['numero']) ?? null;
$cadena=0;
if ($posted) {
    $cadena.=$numbers[$posted] ?? '';
}
echo $cadena;
```

Con eso, sin más historia, tienes todos los dígitos del `0` al `9` resueltos.